# unable to search data in a file in python

Tags: python, cgi

I have a file abcd.txt

```
Shashank  Saxena 24 male
Saurabh Parikh 23 male
Pradip Pillai 32 male
```

I have search.py script which search through this file.
This search.py takes the value from html file and searches in the abcd.txt file. HTML has 4 fields namely Firstname, Lastname,Age and Gender. When in the firstname field the data is entered it is getting searched, but not for others field its not getting searched

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cgi

def get_search():


    found = False

    form = cgi.FieldStorage()
    Fname = form.getvalue('firstname')
    Lname = form.getvalue('lastname')
Age = form.getvalue('age')
Gender = form.getvalue('gender')

print "Content-type:text/html\n"

f = open("/tmp/abcd.txt","r")

for line in f:
    temp = line.split()
    #print temp
    Fsearch = temp[0]
    Lsearch = temp[1]
    Asearch = temp[2]
    Gsearch = temp[3]

    if Fname.lower() in Fsearch.lower():
        print line
        found = True

    if Lname.lower() in Lsearch.lower():
        print line
        found = True

    if Age in Asearch:
        print line
        found = True

    if Gender in Gsearch:
        print line
        found = True

if not found:
    print "No such Records"

    '''
    if Fname in temp or Lname in temp or Age in temp or Gender in temp:
        print "Hello", line
        found = True
if not found:
    print "No matched records"              
    '''
```

get_search()

Comment: Please fix the indentation of code.

Comment: this is the same i am using.No indentation problem

Comment: So `Lname = form.getvalue('lastname')` is the last line of `get_search`? Does not look right to me.

Comment: if i enter value in the lastname field in html, it's not searching in the file. i dont know why ?

Comment: and when i enter the data in firstname field, its getting search and displaying the record, for others field its not....

Comment: help me out. i am going blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that the Values for `Lname`, `Age` and `Gender` are entered correctly?
The rest looks good to me.

Comment: otherwise i would try to rewrite your code to use [FieldStorage.Get list](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html#cgi.FieldStorage.getlist)

Comment: i want for all fields. not just for one field

Comment: well... i tested the python side of your code and it seems to work as expected (one lnie gets printed for every correct value) so the error must either be in the cgi/getvalue part or in your html code

Comment: maybe try `form['firstname'].value` instead of `form.getvalue('firstname')`

Comment: there is some if condition problem i suppose.

Comment: when u enter for lastname field only there is no line printed

Comment: maybe there is an error during execution? Try using `import cgitb` with `cgitb.enable()` to debug your script

Comment: have i written all the IF conditions propoerly or I shall use elif statement after one if statement ?

Comment: I tried this part and for me it worked like this: if `Fname` and `Fsearch` match a the current line is printed. Than if `Lname` and `Lsearch` match the current line is printed again... and so on. If this is the behaviour you want (at the moment) it works fine

Comment: my only Fname and Fsearch match are working fine. My Lname and Lsearch are not matching even though there is a match. It displays nothing in my script. Same for age and ggender

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cgi

def get_search():

    found = False

    form = cgi.FieldStorage()
    Fname = form.getvalue('firstname', '')
    Lname = form.getvalue('lastname', '')
    Age = form.getvalue('age', 0)
    Gender = form.getvalue('gender', '')


    f = open("/tmp/abcd.txt","r")
    b = []
    for line in f:
        temp = line.split()

        Fsearch = temp[0]
        Lsearch = temp[1]
        Asearch = temp[2]
        Gsearch = temp[3]

        if Fname and Fname.lower() in Fsearch.lower():
            found = True

        if Lname and Lname.lower() in Lsearch.lower():
            found = True

        if Age and Age == Asearch:
            found = True

        if Gender and Gender in Gsearch:
            found = True
        if found:
            b.append(line)
        found = False
    f.close()
    print "Content-type:text/html\n"
    if len(b) == 0:
        print "No records found"
    else:
        for each in b:
             print each

get_search()
```